# Xamarin - call fragment method from MainActivity

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager with 3 tab fragments.
The code of tabFragment1 class (Note: V4Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment):

```
class tabFragment1 : V4Fragment
{

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved)
    {
        var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabLayout1, container, false);

        // Set weather icon
        ImageView iv_icon = v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv_icon);
        iv_icon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_weather_cloudy_white_48dp);
        Snackbar.Make(container, "tabFragment; onCreateView()", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
        //UpdateContent(v);
        return v;
    }

    public void UpdateContent(View v)
    {

        // Sample values to read
        string locationCode = "528454";

        // Mapping views
        TextView tv_currentConditions = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentConditions);
        TextView tv_currentTemperature = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentTemperature);
        TextView tv_currentRealFeel = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentRealFeel);
        TextView tv_minMaxTemperature = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.minMaxTemperature);

        // Update view from database
        tv_currentConditions.Text = Sql.ReadValue(locationCode,"currentConditions");
        tv_currentTemperature.Text = Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "currentTemperature") + "°C";
        tv_currentRealFeel.Text = GetString(Resource.String.feelLike) + " " + Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "currentRealFeel") + "°C";
        tv_minMaxTemperature.Text = Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "minTemperature") + " " + Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "maxTemperature") + "°C";

    }

}
```

So, I want to call UpdateContent() method from MainActivity method:

```
public void UpdateCurrentTab()
    {

        ViewPager viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        int currentItem = viewPager.CurrentItem;
        Snackbar.Make(drawerLayout, "CALL TO UPDATE Tab " + currentItem, Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
        View fView = viewPager.GetChildAt(currentItem);
        if (currentItem == 1) { tabFragment1.UpdateContent(fView); }

    }
```

It works fine (cause I see I get correct itemIDs in Snackbar appearing every time I select a tab), but on the last row under if clause ...

```
if (currentItem == 1) { tabFragment1.UpdateContent(fView); }
```

... i see Visual Studio error pop-up saying, that

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'tabFragment1.UpdateContent(fView)'

What is the best way to silve the problem? Thanks

Comment: You try to use `tabFragment1.UpdateContent(fView);` as Extension method, but I don't see it in you code. Did you miss it?

Comment: Maybe that's it. If I understand, I should declare my UpdateContent(View) method like this: public static void UpdateContent(View v), should't I?

Comment: But after that I receive the same error on GetString row (in the same method): tv_currentRealFeel.Text = GetString(Resource.String.feelLike) + " " + Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "currentRealFeel") + "°C";

Comment: `public void UpdateContent(View v)` is object's method not type's method. So for using it you need to create object of `tabFragment1` and call it method. Or you can change declaration for `UpdateContent(View v)` to `static UpdateContent(View v)` and call it as type's method

Comment: Can you add last comment as your answer?

Comment: See the answer. I removed a part of code to reduced the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public void UpdateContent(View v)` is object's method not type's method. So for using it you need to create object of `tabFragment1` and call it method. Or you can change declaration for `UpdateContent(View v)` to `static UpdateContent(View v)` and call it as type's method.

Changing declaration:

```
public static void UpdateContent(View v)
{
    // Put here your code from question       
}
```

And using:

```
public void UpdateCurrentTab()
{
    ViewPager viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
    int currentItem = viewPager.CurrentItem;
    Snackbar.Make(drawerLayout, "CALL TO UPDATE Tab " + currentItem, Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
    View fView = viewPager.GetChildAt(currentItem);
    if (currentItem == 1) 
    { 
        // Now it's a type's method not object's
        tabFragment1.UpdateContent(fView); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Laser42 Do you remeber that for the 1st way you need create new object of tabFragment1's type? Something looks like this `tabFragment1 temp = new tabFragment1(); temp.UpdateContent(fView)`. And 2nd way is above in the answer

Comment: Thank you! If I follow 1st way, I receive an error on the same row, which uses V4Fragment.GetString() function. I added the creation of new tabFragment(), of course ;) The error text is "The fragment [id] isn't attached to activity". If I follow 2nd way, and make my method static, I also get error of an object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Fragment.GetString(int)'. In both cases, the problem is in GetString non-static method

Comment: @Laser42 Can you edit the questions and write your `GetString` method and `Fragment.GetString(int)`?

Comment: I didn't override this method. This is standard Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.GetString(int) method which gets string value from values\strings.xml file

Comment: So, I googled a bit and found that it's common problem with accessing resources from static classes. So, I close this question. And now i think about avoiding direct resource ask from fragments, maybe put values into sqlite db when activity starts. *CRAZY SMILE*